# How to get a viewer screenshot with BIM360 Pushpins and markups from MarkupsCore Extension?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I want to get a viewer screenshot with pushpins made with `Autodesk.BIM360.Extension.PushPin` and markups made with `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992933/autodesk-forge-viewer-api-cannot-load-markups-inside-screenshot?rq=2) related question describes how it's done with canvas and draw image, and other question do the same and even has a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/gOMPYRV?editors=0010), but the markups are displaced:

Real:

[image: img1]

Image:

[image: img2]

So I'm searching through other methods.

getScreenshot method documentation:

[image: docs]

Is this `overlayRenderer` that I'm looking for? If it is, how do I configure it to get the pushpins and markups?

**EDIT**: I have already seen the `html2canvas` library, and the markups are also in the wrong position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `html2canvas`, the previous attempts with this lib failed because:

First try: Screenshot the whole viewer div, that's supposed to get pushpins and markups, but markups went misplaced.

Second try: Screenshot the whole viewer div, but exclude markups passing an identifier to html2canvas config, then create another image with markupsExt.generateData(), and draw these two images into a temporary created canvas. This attempt is a little tricky because it's the same as solution, the difference is that I triggered all my next events inside `svgimage.onload` function, and with this approach, don't know why, markups were not even drawn.

So the solution is wrap the whole logic into a function returning a promise, and resolve the generated image.

Code:

```
                const takeImg = () => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        html2canvas(
                            document.getElementById("mainViewerDiv"),
                            {
                                ignoreElements: (element) =>
                                    element.getAttribute(
                                        "layer-order-id"
                                    ) === "markups-svg",
                            }
                        ).then((canvas) => {
                            canvas.toBlob(
                                async function (blob) {
                                    const viewerImg = new Image();
                                    const viewerImgUrl =
                                        URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                    viewerImg.src = viewerImgUrl;
                                    viewerImg.onload = function () {
                                        const newCanvas =
                                            document.createElement(
                                                "canvas"
                                            );
                                        newCanvas.width = viewerImg.width;
                                        newCanvas.height = viewerImg.height;
                                        const svgImg = new Image();

                                        const svgString =
                                            this.mk_ext.generateData();

                                        const svgBlob = new Blob(
                                            [svgString],
                                            {type: "image/svg+xml",});
                                        const svgUrl =
                                            URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
                                        svgImg.src = svgUrl;
                                        svgImg.onload = async function () {
                                            const ctx =
                                                newCanvas.getContext("2d");
                                            ctx.drawImage(viewerImg, 0, 0);
                                            ctx.drawImage(svgImg, 0, 0);

                                            resolve(
                                                newCanvas.toDataURL(
                                                    "image/png"
                                                )
                                            );
                                        };
                                    }.bind(this);
                                }.bind(this)
                            );
                        });
                    });
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is if you use the same dimensions for the image that the Viewer is using.  
Updated code for https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/gOMPYRV

```
forgist.setup(document.getElementById('viewer'), 2).then(viewer => {
  viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
  viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui');
  document.getElementById('get-screenshot').addEventListener('click', 
    async function () {
      //const dataUrl = await getScreenshotDataUrl(viewer, viewer.container.clientWidth, 1920, 1080);
      const dataUrl = await getScreenshotDataUrl(viewer, viewer.container.clientWidth, viewer.container.clientHeight);
      let tab = window.open();
      //tab.document.body.innerHTML = `<img src="${dataUrl}" width="1920" height="1080">`;
      tab.document.body.innerHTML = `<img src="${dataUrl}" width="${viewer.container.clientWidth}" height="${viewer.container.clientHeight}">`;
  });
});
```

Then you can crop the image to some other size if needed, like it's done e.g. here: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the answer, with these modifications, in my test, markups are on the right place but the PushPins doesn't, any idea of how to put them in screenshot?